# GNS3 is not showing console to the virtualbox virtual machines

Tags: console, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualhost

GNS3 is not showing the connected virtualbox VMs, however I can see the state is running. Only console from routers are shown.

If I try to run VMs directly from virtualbox, and console is displayed properly, state of course is also running.

So seems that for some reason GNS3 is not displaying VMs, even if they are running.

I was following this instructions, using exactly the same options: http://www.gns3.net/documentation/gns3/virtualbox-emulation/ and running GNS3 and virtualbox under Debian GNU/Linux 64 bits.

**Workaround found:** at least using serial connection I can connect, to do that I followed the next steps:

1. If I activate: "Enable console support"
2. Install minicom (e.g.: apt-get install minicom).
3. Later "minicom -s" and configure using "/dev/ttyS0" as a port instead "/dev/modem".
4. Run again the topology in gns3 and press the button of the menu of "show all consoles".

Not sure if I still have access by normal terminal instead console port.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ttyS0 settings as kernel boot parameter:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX='console=tty0 console=ttyS0,19200n8'
GRUB_TERMINAL=serial
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=19200 --unit=0 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1"
```

then execute update-grub as root:

`# update-grub`

this can be your template

see this post for more infomation: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-serial-console-on-debian-linux/